Bevel Doesnt Work with Mirror?
Im new to blender and this forum and i have a problem using blender,
im trying to make my cube sharp (trying to make a sword...) but when i use the mirror i cant bevel the edges.
It doesnt matter if i select both edges or one.
Does anyone know what im doing wrong?


It looks as if you have every edge on your model selected. Which edge are you trying to bevel? Sharing your Blend file would help so that we can see what you're doing.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the full link into it.

And it looks as if you have geometry crossing the mirror axis and overlapping itself...
